# What does rosdep init do?

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I was wondering what does the following command exactly do and why do we need it?

```
pi@tenzo ~ $ sudo rosdep init
Wrote /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/20-default.list
```

Why do we need to run the update command afterwards?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216350/what-does-rosdep-init-do?/) by [UserK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22118/userk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2015-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The source of rosdep key entries are maintained on [rosdistro repository](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/tree/master/rosdep) and frequently updated.

> Why do we need to run the update command afterwards?

After `rosdep update` you probably saw something was done at `~/.ros/rosdep/sources.cache`. That's where the latest rosdep key entries are stored in some files that get updated with the rosdep command.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [UserK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22118/userk/) on 2015-08-24**:
Thanks 130. Clean answer!